# If statement not working for triple digits?

Tags: swift, if-statement

So here's the simple problem.

```
 if cell.count.text == "\(0)"
    {
        cell.pText.textColor = UIColor.grayColor()
        cell.nicebutton!.setImage(UIImage(named:"defaulltup"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        cell.nopebutton!.setImage(UIImage(named:"defaultdown"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        cell.count.textColor = UIColor.grayColor()
        cell.time.textColor = UIColor.grayColor()
    }
    if cell.count.text >= "\(1)"
    {
        cell.pText.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        //cell.time.textColor = UIColor(red: 42.0/255, green: 204.0/255, blue: 113.0/255, alpha: 1)
        cell.count.textColor = UIColor(red: 42.0/255, green: 204.0/255, blue: 113.0/255, alpha: 1)
        cell.nicebutton!.setImage(UIImage(named:"upgreen"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        cell.nopebutton!.setImage(UIImage(named:"defaultdown"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        //cell.nopebutton!.setImage(UIImage(named:"downred"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        cell.count.textColor = UIColor(red: 42.0/255, green: 204.0/255, blue: 113.0/255, alpha: 1)
    }
    if cell.count.text < "\(0)"
    {
        cell.pText.textColor = UIColor(red: 231.0/255, green: 76.0/255, blue: 50.0/255, alpha: 1)
        //cell.time.textColor = UIColor(red: 231.0/255, green: 76.0/255, blue: 50.0/255, alpha: 1)
        cell.count.textColor = UIColor(red: 231.0/255, green: 76.0/255, blue: 50.0/255, alpha: 1)
        cell.nicebutton!.setImage(UIImage(named:"defaulltup"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        //cell.nicebutton!.setImage(UIImage(named:"upgreen"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        cell.nopebutton!.setImage(UIImage(named:"downred"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)

    }
    if cell.count.text >= "\(99)"
    {

        cell.pText.textColor = UIColor(red: 249.0/255, green: 191.0/255, blue: 59.0/255, alpha: 1)
        //cell.nopebutton!.setImage(UIImage(named:"downred"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        cell.nicebutton!.setImage(UIImage(named:"golden"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        cell.count.textColor = UIColor(red: 249.0/255, green: 191.0/255, blue: 59.0/255, alpha: 1)
    }
```

The last if statement isn't working at ALL, while the others are working just as they should. I'm really confused as to why this is the case.

Comment: @JAL no their values are strings.

Comment: You are comparing *strings*, which means that – for example – "200" < "99".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, in your code you're comparing strings (**not** numbers contained in strings) using `<` and `>` operators. That is probably not what you want to do. According to the Swift docs:

> For characters in strings, “greater than” means “appears later in the
>   alphabet than”

The comparison results for strings are different than if you just compared the numbers, so for example the expression `"2" > "10"` is true, while of course `2 > 10` is false.

If you want to compare the numbers contained in the strings, you can do this instead:

```
if cell.count.text.toInt() == 0
// etc.
```

Also, it would help you avoid bugs if you wrote your `if` conditions like this:

```
if condition1 {
    //...
}
else if condition2 {
    //...
}
else {
    //...
}
```

In your current code, if one of the conditions is incorrect, more than one block of code can be executed for the same value of `cell.count.text`.

Comment: My problem was that since it was working as I thought it should, I figured it was following conventional rules. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that you are comparing strings and expecting them to behave the same as integers. Unfortunately, this is not the case. You can easily check this:

```
print("100" > "99")
```

You will get an output of False. As far as characters go, 9 comes after 1, so 99 is always greater than 100. My advice is to convert cell.count.text to an Int and then make your comparisons. Note that converting to an Int produces an Optional so you have to use if let to bind the value.

```
if let count = cell.count.text.toInt() {
    if count < 0 {
        // Do something useful here
    }

    if count > 99 {
        // Do something useful here
    }
}
else {
    // Handle the case where cell.count.text isn't a valid integer
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Move this code:

```
if cell.count.text >= 99
```

above:

```
if cell.count.text >= 1
```